# subsubsection not working in my thesis macro

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm unable get the `\subsubsection` layer using my thesis scripts. It works fine up to subsection but not beyond that level. The counters have been set to a depth of 3 and so should be working for `\subsubsection` but it doesn't. The necessary files are:

- [`ucr.cls`](http://pastebin.com/GMfj93Sq)
- [`uct10.clo`](http://pastebin.com/cHe5VCMr)
- [`uct11.clo`](http://pastebin.com/mqAFAJj8)
- [`uct12.clo`](http://pastebin.com/Gd6DYWQU)
- [`sw20uctd.sty`](http://pastebin.com/5VxxhLyA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document class loads a font-specific `.clo` file, depending on the font size option given at loading:

- `10pt` (default, if nothing is specified): loads `uct10.clo`;
- `11pt`: loads `uct11.clo`; and
- `12pt`: loads `uct12.clo`

You'll see the line(s)

```
356: % The value of the counter secnumdepth gives the depth of the
357: % highest-level sectioning command that is to produce section numbers.
358: %
359:  
360: \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
```

in each of those files. So, even though `ucr.cls` contains the line

```
138: \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

which should allow section numbers up to the `\subsubsection` level to be displayed, it's overwritten when the respective `.clo` is loaded. Either fix this inside the `.clo` files, or change the `.cls` to issue (say)

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}}
```

or just issue

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

inside your preamble.

Comment: This solved my issues and saved me a deal of headache